# Find word that has more than 50 characters in all php files

Tags: find, grep

I am trying to use find in combination with grep to find all the php files in my web server which have a word (any sequence of characters except whitespace) with more than 50 characters.

I have this base:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec fgrep -q '.{50}' {} \; -print
```

But is not working as expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`.` stands for everything except for newline characters, including spaces and tabs. That's why your regular expression will match lines longer than 50 characters.

To match words that are at least 50 characters long you can use something like this:

```
[^\s]{50}
```

`[^\s]` matches everything except for whitespace characters. `{50}` means that sequence of 50 such (not necessarily identical) characters will be matched.